# Scaffolding in ASP.NET MVC5 (MvcMusicStore Tutorial)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Firstly, if anyone knows the book Professional ASP.NET MVC5 I'm referring to page 87 but in general it's referencing the MvcMusicStore tutorial - scaffolding a store manager section.

Is there a reason we create a new db context instead of using the
    existing ApplicationDbContext?

I want to stamp any changes to an album with a userID so added the following to the Album class.

```
public virtual ApplicationUser SubmittedBy { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

but when I try to add a controler as per p87 in the book I get the below error, even after cleaning, building and rebuilding the project.

I also added the following to ApplicationUser class to try to resolve the issue but no joy

```
[Key]
public virtual int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

Could the issue be that the IdentityModels with their own DbContext are in the same folder as the rest of my models?

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'Unable to retrieve metadata for
>   'MvcMusicStorePrototype.Models.Album'.
>
> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined.
>   Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is
>   based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based
>   on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Installed package versions are as follow:

> Id                             Version
>   Description/Release Notes
>
> --                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                               Antlr                          3.4.1.9004           ANother Tool for
>   Language Recognition, is a language tool that provides a framework for
>   constructing recognizers, in... bootstrap                      3.0.0
>   Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and
>   easier web development.                               EntityFramework 
>   6.1.1                Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.
>   jQuery                         1.10.2               jQuery is a new
>   kind of JavaScript Library....
>   jQuery.Validation              1.11.1               This jQuery plugin
>   makes simple clientside form validation trivial, while offering lots
>   of option for customization.... Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0
>   Core interfaces for ASP.NET Identity.
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.E... 2.1.0                ASP.NET Identity
>   providers that use Entity Framework.
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 2.1.0                Owin
>   implementation for ASP.NET Identity.
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc           5.2.0                This package
>   contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC gives you
>   a powerful, patterns-based way t... Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
>   3.2.0                This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web Pages. ASP.NET Web Pages and the new Razor syntax provi...
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi... 1.1.3                ASP.NET
>   Optimization introduces a way to bundle and optimize CSS and
>   JavaScript files.
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages      3.2.0                This package
>   contains core runtime assemblies shared between ASP.NET MVC and
>   ASP.NET Web Pages.
>   Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusiv... 3.2.0                jQuery plugin that
>   unobtrusively sets up jQuery.Validation.
>   Microsoft.Owin                 2.1.0                Provides a set of
>   helper types and abstractions for simplifying the creation of OWIN
>   components.                        Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 
>   2.1.0                OWIN server that enables OWIN-based applications to run on IIS using the ASP.NET request pipeline.
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security        2.1.0                Common types which
>   are shared by the various authentication middleware components.
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Coo... 2.1.0                Middleware that
>   enables an application to use cookie based authentication, similar to
>   ASP.NET's forms authentication.   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Fac... 2.1.0
>   Middleware that enables an application to support Facebook's OAuth 2.0
>   authentication workflow.
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google 2.1.0                Contains
>   middlewares to support Google's OpenId and OAuth 2.0 authentication
>   workflows.
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Mic... 2.1.0                Middleware that
>   enables an application to support the Microsoft Account authentication
>   workflow.                        Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth  2.1.0 
>   Middleware that enables an application to support any standard OAuth
>   2.0 authentication workflow.                       Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twi... 2.1.0                Middleware that
>   enables an application to support Twitter's OAuth 2.0 authentication
>   workflow.                          Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
>   1.0.0.0              This package contains the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure assembly that lets you dynamically
>   register HTTP modules at r... Modernizr                      2.6.2
>   Modernizr adds classes to the  element which allow you to target
>   specific browser functionality in your styles... Newtonsoft.Json
>   6.0.3                Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET
>   Owin                           1.0                  OWIN IAppBuilder
>   startup interface
>   Respond                        1.2.0                The goal of this
>   script is to provide a fast and lightweight (3kb minified / 1kb
>   gzipped) script to enable responsiv... WebGrease
>   1.5.2                Web Grease is a suite of tools for optimizing javascript, css files and images.

Comment: are you sure that the code in the book is using Microsoft.Asp.NET Identity 2.0? It's drastically different from Identity 1.0 or SimpleAuthentication.

Comment: @Claies the book is using OAuth so I guess that's Identity 2.0?

Comment: not necessarily. OAuth is a pattern, Identity is a set of classes that implement the pattern.  You can do OAuth without Identity, or with Identity 1.0....

Comment: put it another way; did the instructions in the book tell you to select an authentication option when you created the project?

Comment: I'm opening the sample code for the book now, to look at what it is using.

Comment: @Claies - just single login auth

Comment: I downloaded the sample project from the book errata, opened the project, added the two lines listed here, and it compiled perfectly.  did you modify the IdentityModels.cs file?

Comment: @Claies - mine compiles too, I get the error when I try to scaffold a controller with views. I have tried with the IdentityModels.cs untouched and with many different ammendments according to similar problems (like giving them a [Key] and overriding OnModelCreating, etc)

Comment: ok definitely an issue with the project, I get the same errors with scaffolding.  I don't own a copy of the book, so I don't really have a way to verify right this second what's going on or if there is a step missing here.

Comment: @Claies I left a post on the book's website but alas no answers have been forthcoming. In fairness I'm straying from the book by bringing IdentityUsers into the mix but I think I have found my answer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx?PageIndex=2. I'll read it tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: @Claies - found the solution, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Application User's Id is a string. I followed [this article](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/13/ASPNET-Identity-20-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Using-Integer-Keys-Instead-of-Strings.aspx) in order to convert the Id type to int and then created Id's for the users.

A lot of work just to change the id data type from string to int but there we go. I could have just used strings I guess but I'd rather all my key data types be the same.